# Exit status of last command using PROMPT_COMMAND

Tags: bash, logs, exit-status

I want to save the exit status of the last ran command (in a file, in a variable, it doesn't really matter), but this must be done automatically in an interactive shell, manually running something like `var=$?` is not an option.

I decided to try to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to accomplish this. Below you can see me proving that what I tried didn't work.

```
/home/exit_status$ export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo $?"                           
0                                                                   
/home/exit_status$ rm /                                                      
rm: cannot remove ‘/’: Is a directory                               
0                                                                   
/home/exit_status$ echo $?                                                   
1                                                                   
0
```

How do I go about making it so that the snippet above works as I intend? I can work out how to store it, I don't need help with that. I just mentioned that to give context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you used double quotes, `$?` is getting expanded when you assign the value - as you can verify using `set -x`:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND="echo $?"
+ PROMPT_COMMAND='echo 0'
++ echo 0
0
```

If you change the double quotes to single quotes, you should get the desired behaviour:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='echo $?'
+ PROMPT_COMMAND='echo $?'
++ echo 0
0
```

i.e.

```
$ set +x
+ set +x
0
$ ls nofile
ls: cannot access 'nofile': No such file or directory
2
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a var after the command.

```
/home/exit_status$ export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo $?"                           
0                                                                   
/home/exit_status$ rm /                                                      
rm: cannot remove ‘/’: Is a directory                               
0                                                                   
/home/exit_status$ u=$?                                                   
0
/home/exit_status$ echo $u
1                                                
0
```

- `$u` will host the status until reset.
- you can't insert `u=$?` into `PROMPT_COMMAND` as `$u` will be overwriten by each command.
- on a side note, I am unsure this will work in a script.